# Spring boot + React integration/Security when building a web app

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, jwt

I am trying to build my first website using Spring boot + ReactJS and MySQL.
It's essentially a gym website where users can create an account, sign in and then choose a membership + checkout etc.

**What I have done so far is:**

1. Spring Boot REST Api for creating a new customer + other CRUD features.
2. React Front End Registration form with Spring boot server validation, the form posts the data to the REST api using axios.
3. I have a design in figma of the website and I've been working on that in the meanwhile because honestly, i am stuck.

**Some problems I'm facing:**

1. Spring Security, I have used JSP before and it was easier for me to get the hang of it since it is server sided and I just had controller methods etc. Now that I'm using react I have no idea how the security function would work with Spring Boot.

   Since the front and back end are served on different ports, how would my Spring configure
   method look like? (The class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter).

   How do I restrict access to URL's on the front end using React Router? Since Spring Boot and React router are both on different ends I am struggling to understand how that works? What about the API endpoints being accessible as well.
2. Authentication + Authorization, I've looked up tutorials and I've pretty much only seen Authentication by the use of JWT tokens when working with Spring Boot + React, is there no other option other than JWT? (For me it looks really confusing so I'd like to know if there's a valid alternative or not) - if not , why JWT?
3. I know Spring Security on its own is a complicated framework and I've read a alot about it, though some concepts do confuse me. (UserDetailsService vs UserDetails, Types of Authentication Managers you get)
4. In general, the integration of Spring Boot with a SPA such as react, if someone could explain the flow of how it functions on both the front and back end.

Answer (score 1):

Not long ago i had similar problems like u. I would suggest to check out this tutorial: https://youtu.be/VVn9OG9nfH0
It should answer all of your questions.